Vertex AI Function Calling Fails to Escape Quote
I'm using Gemini 1.5 Pro on Vertex AI to tag attributes about people. I'm using the forced function calling feature to force the model to output JSON in the provided schema. One of the attributes is a biography string. The model fails to generate quotation symbols in this string—where a quote symbol should appear, the string attribute simply ends. It does not cause the JSON output to be invalid, merely that string attribute to stop.
Here is a reproducible example:
"""Helper functions for interacting with Vertex AI's LLMs"""

import os

import vertexai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.auth import default
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import (FunctionDeclaration, Tool,
                                                ToolConfig)

load_dotenv()


SCHEMA = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "summary": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Summary about the person, using full sentences.",
        },
    },
    "required": ["bullet_points"],
}

PROMPT = "The person's summary should be exactly this: The person's name is Jack."
SYSTEM = "You are a person summarizer."

credentials, _ = default()
vertexai.init(project=os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT_NAME"), location="us-east4", credentials=credentials)

tool = Tool(
    function_declarations=[
        FunctionDeclaration(
            name="generate_content",
            parameters=SCHEMA,
        )
    ]
)

tool_config = ToolConfig(
    function_calling_config=ToolConfig.FunctionCallingConfig(
        mode=ToolConfig.FunctionCallingConfig.Mode.ANY,
        allowed_function_names=["generate_content"],
    )
)

model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro", tools=[tool], tool_config=tool_config, system_instruction=SYSTEM)

response = model.generate_content(
    PROMPT,
    generation_config={
        "max_output_tokens": 200,
        "temperature": 0,
    },
    tools=[tool],
    tool_config=tool_config,
)

fc = response.candidates[0].content.parts[0].function_call

print(type(fc).to_dict(fc)["args"])

The output of the above script is the following:
{"summary": "The person"}
whereas it should clearly be
{"summary": "The person's name is Jack."}
Am I missing something about stop sequences or other parameters? Or is this a bug with Vertex AI?
As a temporarily solution, I'm adding "Make sure to escape any quote symbols in the summary." to the system prompt. Clearly, this is a hack, though, and may not work sometimes.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand The model fails to generate quotation symbols in this string—where a quote symbol should appear, the string attribute simply ends. It does not cause the JSON output to be invalid, merely that string attribute to stop.. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I just updated the answer to reflect this. It outputs a JSON object where the summary cuts off right before the quote symbol

Thank you for replying. When I tested your request, I obtaned {"summary": "The person's name is Jack."}. For example, when you test model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro", tools=[tool]), will the result be changed?

Do you mean eliminate the tool_config parameter. I can try that. If you run it a few times, you always get the same full response?

This issue is now fixed. Use the model gemini-1.5-pro-002 (or gemini-1.5-flash-002. The response is now
{'summary': "The person\\'s name is Jack."}.
